# Why Can't I delete this row from my table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

currently learning from a textbook, still very new.
I'm trying to delete this row from my table called classics, however, when I try to it won't let me.

```
+---------------------+------------------------------+------------+------+---------+
| author              | title                        | type       | year | ISBN    |
+---------------------+------------------------------+------------+------+---------+
| Mark Tawin          | The Adventures of Tom Sawyer | Fiction    | 1876 | 978159  |
| JANE AUSTEN         | PRIDE AND PREJIDUCE          | FICTION    | 1811 | 978058  |
| Mark Twain          | Adventures of Tom Sawyer     | Fiction    | 1876 | 978159  |
| Jane Austen         | Pride and Prejudice          | Fiction    | 1811 | 978058  |
| Charles Darwin      | The Origin of Species        | Nonfiction | 1856 | 978051  |
| Charles Dickens     | The Old Curiosity Shop       | Fiction    | 1841 | 9780099 |
| William Shakespeare | Romeo and Juliet             | Play       | 1594 | 9780192 |
+---------------------+------------------------------+------------+------+---------+
```

This is the table currently, I'm trying to drop it using

```
ALTER TABLE classics DROP COLUMN `Mark Tawin`;
```

I've tried many variations of this as well, but it just doesn't seem to be working.
Here's the table description if it helps.

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| author | varchar(128) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| title  | varchar(128) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| type   | varchar(16)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| year   | char(4)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ISBN   | char(13)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: As far as I see, your table does not contain a column called `Mark Tawin`. Did you try to use a common `DELETE`  query to remove the **row** with that value?

Comment: Your question is so ill founded I'm scared to tell you what to do as I'm afraid you'll only make whatever your problem is worse.

Comment: @NicoHaase , I thought it does? I may be getting the terminology confused. I'm still very new.

Comment: @Kevin I don't really mind, the database is not very new at all. Shouldn't be an issue worst case I can just delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DROP COLUMN` removes columns not rows. As I understand your requirement you ness a

```
delete from classics where author =  `Mark Tawin`
```

Comment: Is the column different from the row? Does the column refer to the things in the table when I use describe and row is when I use select * from classics?

Comment: @Seco01 Yes.  Column and row are two very different things.  The column is part of the table structure that defines what kind of data the table holds.  The row is an entry in the table that has the data for a specific record

Comment: The solution above worked, which is odd I thought I tried it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are right. A column is vertical a row horizontal.